# Password login for ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, password-protection

I am currently developing an app for a company that is in a very competitive field. I have finished all of the features of the app that they requested except for one, making it somehow protected from their competing companies to download and use. I thought that I could set up a UIViewController with a password field that would check against some kind of database, but I'm not sure how to do the checking against a database part nor the practicality of it, and was hoping I could get some ideas on how to do this so that other companies couldn't steal and use this app without a password or something that changes like every 30 days or something and is kind of like an activation code.

Comment: if your ap is to be AppStored and charged for downloads, how could it de stealed?

Comment: what is their actual requirement regarding that "protection"?

Comment: Why are you not distributing it as an enterprise app?

Comment: I'm not doing it as an enterprise app because it down't work for this companies lay out, they provide the resources to independent saelsman whom they are worried will turn around and give it away to their competitors.

Comment: Also the protection required is that it needs to be able to be deactivated so that if they stop doing business with a salesman he can no longer use the app.

Comment: You should have a list of the salespeople in a database, and their individual log-in information linked to it.  So when they try to log in, the app will check the database to see if they are still active.  The initial log-in could be created by the company, rather than the individual users.  If they operated it like a subscription service, that would solve the problem.

Comment: That might work, but how would i set up the database? within the app? on a webserver?

Comment: I have setup a web server with a database of some activation codes and all that, but the prioblem i am having now is that when i send a request (using ASIHTTPRequest) I don't know how to get a response. I tried JSON but it isn't working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing (if everyone needs a reference) was setting up a server with an SQL table that has pass codes in it. Since apple does not allow for any sort of system that requires you to "buy the app from outside the app store" I made a dumby username field (shame on me) that takes any value you like and then requires to have a pass code that fits. Once the pass code gets authenticated with the web server in a json sql request (there are plenty of api's to do this with) it comes back and sends the user to the first screen and sets a value in a plist with how many days of use the user has left. Whenever the user opens up the app it checks to see if the date is different from the last date logged in (saved in the same plist file) and if it is different then it calculates the difference and deducts that many. When the count reaches 0 it sends the user to the pass code authentication screen again. A bit complicated but an effective method of getting around Apple's restriction on not having a sort of pass code system like this. Thanks for the answers, unfortunately enterprise did not work for this company since they needed to be able to distribute the app to as many 3rd party members as they wanted to without having to worry about them leaving the company for other suppliers and remote management of the app (I.e ability to remote uninstall) was also not an option. Hope this helps someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

Review the WWDC 2012 video "Building and Distributing Custom B2B Apps for iOS".  I'm unsure if your app is in this B2B classification, it seems that it might be from your description.

Comment: That would work but I also need to be able to stop people from being able to use the app at any moment, thus the idea of stop giving them the activation code. Also it needs to be readily available to them since these are independent sales men and women and cannot have access to a VPP.